# Find $|{\rm Aut}(D_8\times S_3)|$ using a particular result about Remak decompositions.

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, automorphism-group, dihedral-groups, direct-product

This is **Exercise 3.3.9** of Robinson's *"A Course in the Theory of Groups (Second Edition)"*. According to [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%7B%5Crm%20Aut%7D(D_8%5Ctimes%20S_3)%24&p=10), it is new to MSE.

### The Details:

On page 6, *ibid*, the *dihedral group* $D_{2n}$ of order $2n$ is defined as the symmetry group of a regular $n$-gon.

On page 28, *ibid.*,

> A *right operator group* is a triple $(G, \Omega, \alpha)$ consisting of a group $G$, a set $\Omega$ called the *operator domain* and a function $\alpha:G\times \Omega\to G$ such that $g\mapsto (g,\omega)\alpha$ is an endomorphism of $G$ for each $\omega\in\Omega$. We shall write $g^\omega$ for $(g,\omega)\alpha$ and speak of the *$\Omega$-group* if the function $\alpha$ is understood.
>
> [. . .]
>
> If $G$ is an $\Omega$-group, an *$\Omega$-subgroup* of $G$ is a subgroup $H$ which is *$\Omega$-admissible*, that is, such that $h^\omega\in H$ whenever $h\in H$ and $\omega\in\Omega$.

On page 60, *ibid.*,

> [Consider] a partially ordered set $\Lambda$ with partial order $\le$. We say that $\Lambda$ satisfies the *maximal condition* of each nonempty subset $\Lambda_0$ contains at least one *maximal element*.

Analogously, the *minimal condition* is defined.

On page 80, *ibid.*,

> Let $G$ be a group with operator domain $\Omega$. An $\Omega$-subgroup $H$ is called an *$\Omega$-direct factor* of $G$ If there exists an $\Omega$-subgroup $K$ such that $G=H\times K$; then $K$ is called an *$\Omega$-direct complement* of $H$ in $G$. If there are no proper nontrivial $\Omega$-direct factors of $G$, then $G$ is said to be *$\Omega$-indecomposable* [. . .].

On page 81, *ibid*

> [The maximal and minimal conditions on $\Omega$-direct factors being equivalent guarantees that an] $\Omega$-group may be expressed as a direct product of finitely many nontrivial $\Omega$-indecomposable subgroups: such a direct decomposition is called a *Remak decomposition*.
>
> **Theorem (Remak):** If an $\Omega$-group $G$ has the minimal condition on $\Omega$-direct factors, it has a Remak decomposition.

On page 92, *ibid.*, there are the following three exercises:

> **Exercise 3.3.4:** Prove that the central automorphisms of a group $G$ form a subgroup ${\rm Aut}_{{\rm c}}\ G$ of ${\rm Aut}\ G$.

*Proof:* Simply apply the one-step subgroup test.$\square$

> **Exercise 3.3.5 (J.E. Adney and Ti Yen):** Let $G$ be a finite group which has no nontrivial abelian direct factors. Prove that $\lvert{\rm Aut}_{{\rm c}}\ G\rvert =\lvert {\rm Hom}(G_{{\rm ab}}, Z(G))\rvert$. Deduce that if $G$ has no nontrivial central automorphisms, then $Z(G)\le G'$.

*Proof:* This follows rather easily from the hint: "If $\alpha\in {\rm Aut}_{{\rm c}}\ G$, define $\theta_\alpha\in{\rm Hom}(G_{{\rm ab}}, Z(G))$ by $(gG')^{\theta_\alpha}=g^{-1}g^\alpha$. Show that $\alpha\mapsto \theta_\alpha$ is a bijection."$\square$

> **Exercise 3.3.8:** Let $G=G_1\times\dots\times G_k$ be a Remak decomposition of a finite group $G$. Assume no two of the $G_i$ are isomorphic. Denote by $A$ the subgroup of all automorphisms of $G$ that leave each $G_i$ invariant. Prove the following:
>
> (i) $A\cong{\rm Aut}(G_1)\times\dots\times{\rm Aut}(G_k)$.
>
> (ii) ${\rm Aut}(G)=A({\rm Aut}_{{\rm c}}(G))$.
>
> (iii) ${\rm Aut}(G)=A$ if and only if $G$ has only one Remak decomposition.

*Proof sketch:*
(i) This follows readily from the definition of $A$.

(ii) The inclusion ${\rm Aut}(G)\supseteq A({\rm Aut}_{{\rm c}}(G))$ is clear from the definition of a set product. *I'm stuck on the inclusion, ${\rm Aut}(G)\subseteq A({\rm Aut}_{{\rm c}}(G))$. I don't think it would be particularly edifying to figure out, so I've moved on.*

(iii) This follows from Adney & Yen's Lemma above.$\square$

### The Question:

> Find the order of ${\rm Aut}(D_8\times S_3)$ (using **Exercise 3.3.8**).

### Thoughts:

I can see this splits into three stages:

1. Prove $G=D_8\times S_3$ is a Remak decomposition.
2. Prove that this Remak decomposition of $G$ is unique.${}^\dagger$
3. Somehow determine the order of the automorphism group of $G$ by way of, mostly, **Exercise 3.3.8.**

---

According to GAP,

```
gap> Size(AutomorphismGroup(DirectProduct(DihedralGroup(8),SymmetricGroup(3))));
96
gap>
```

the order of ${\rm Aut}(G)$ is $96.$

---

I have no idea how to do stage 3.

---

If $G$ has unique Remak decomposition${}^\dagger$

$$D_8\times S_3,$$

then ${\rm Aut}(G)\cong {\rm Aut}(D_8)\times {\rm Aut}(S_3)$.

We have [$\lvert {\rm Aut}(D_8)\rvert=8$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1205086/104041) and [$\lvert{\rm Aut}(S_3)\rvert=6$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/773154/104041). I'm not sure whether that helps.

---

$\dagger:$ It's not unique. (See the comments.) This follows from the GAP calculation. However, I feel like this is cheating.

---

Please help :)

Comment: You know from your GAP calculation that $A = {\rm Aut}(D_8) \times {\rm Aut}(S_3)$ is a proper subgroup of  ${\rm Aut}(G)$, so $G$ cannot have a unique Remak decompostion. Following Exercise 3.3.8, you could try and calculate ${\rm Aut_c}(G)$. Then if you can calculate $A \cap {\rm Aut_c}(G)$ you will be able to use Exercise 3.3.8 to calculate $|{\rm Aut}(G)|$.

Comment: By the way, in this and you previous question, you are spending some time discussing $\Omega$-groups, $\Omega$-decompositions, etc., but (as far as I can see) they are not really relevant to these questions, because the $\Omega$-actions involved are trivial. We are talking about normal direct product decompositions, not decompositions w.r.t some nontrivial action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the proof of 3.3.8 (ii), apply the Krull-Remak-Schmidt theorem (thm 3.3.8 in Robinson) to

$$\begin{align}
G &= G_1 \times \cdots \times G_k \\
&= \phi(G_1) \times \cdots \times \phi(G_k),
\end{align}$$

where $\phi \in \operatorname{Aut}(G)$.

For your main question, let $G = D_8 \times S_3$.

Apply ex. 3.3.8 to conclude $\operatorname{Aut}(G) = A \operatorname{Aut}_c(G)$. Then apply ex. 3.3.8 and ex 3.3.5  to conclude $|A| = 48$, $|\operatorname{Aut}_c(G)| = 8$, and $|A \cap \operatorname{Aut}_c(G)| = 4$.

Conclude that $|\operatorname{Aut}(G)| = 96$.